# Destroy and Re-Create Model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a small guestbook-like ruby on rails project which has a model "users" used by several other models to keep track of who posts which comments and so on.

Now, I would like to replace my current "users" model with one generated using devise.

I am a bit unsure how to this however. I assume I should somehow destroy the previous models, and then use the devise command to generate a new users model.

My is, can I destroy and re-create my model without this breaking the application? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started
Devise adds the necessary columns to your model so you don't have to destroy it.

Comment: Ok, so it won't break my model? What if some of the columns used by devise already exist and have been populated with data?

Comment: you can try to generate model and you will see a new migration file. Check it to be sure that new columns are really new. PS I beleive it is true because you can see [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/1fbc165b985b85f70c8df188299fc2e23a4963da/lib/generators/active_record/devise_generator.rb#L39-L70) that column's names are rather informative and original, so I doubt that you have already any of the column in your table `users`